# ansible rpy2 install with pip complain about R's home

Tags: ansible, rpy2

I in role using pip: on a virtualenv:

```
- name: pip Install packages into virtualenv
  pip: >
    name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}"
    virtualenv_site_packages="no"
  with_items:
    - rpy2
```

I get this error when installing `rpy2`:

```
failed: [vagrant] => (item=rpy2) => {"cmd": "/home/toto/venv  /bin/pip install rpy2",
                                      "failed": true, "item": "rpy2"}
msg: stdout: Collecting rpy2
Downloading rpy2-2.7.8.tar.gz (178kB)
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.
```

How to inform in an ansible way that the R home is in ~/R ?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to place R in the `PATH`.

If I am understanding [ansible's doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-can-i-set-the-path-or-any-other-environment-variable-for-a-task-or-entire-playbook) correctly (I don't know/use ansible), this is done with something like:

```
environment:
  PATH: "/your/home/R:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```